# How can I get the PHP linter output right in vim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, php

I'm using PHP linter to check syntax errors in PHP , right from vim
with that command : 
:!PHP -l "%"
when I do that, ( I'm on Windows ) , Windows open another CMD and the result of the parsing is displayed in that window.

**Is it possible to get the output of the linter right into vim, either in the bottom of vim or maybe in a readonly buffer at the bottom of my screen ?**

Answer (score 1):

Try doing "`:compiler php`", then "`:make %`".  If errors are reported, Vim will jump to the first one.  You can also view them by typing "`:cwindow`" or "`:copen`".  This involves the QuickFix system, see "`:help quickfix.txt`" to learn more about it.

Comment: I tried this, but although php reports errors, vim says there are no errors and `:cwindow` doesn't display anything.

Comment: What version of Vim? What operating system? What version of PHP? What is the exact command-line command you are running?